# Need Shell Script for WAS restart

Tags: shell, deployment, websphere, restart

I am looking for a shell (wrapper) script to do the below activity.

1.Stop the WAS servers.
2.Call the actual deploy.py script maintained by some other  team.
3.Start the WAS servers.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find below a simple script to do the activities you mentioned.
Update the variables before running the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set the environment variables
#set was_home, eg : /opt/ibm/Websphere/ProcServer
WAS_HOME=
#set the profile name, eg : Node01
PROFILE_NAME=
#set the server name, eg: server1
SERVER_NAME=
#Set the filelocation for the deploy script, eg : /var/scripts/deploy.py
DEPLOY_SCRIPT=

#stop server
${WAS_HOME}/profiles/${PROFILE_NAME}/bin/stopServer.sh ${SERVER_NAME} -username <admin username> -password <admin password>

#Run deploy script
${WAS_HOME}/profiles/${PROFILE_NAME}/bin/wsadmin.sh -lang jython -host <dmgr hostname> -port <dmgr soap port> -username <admin username> -password <admin password> -f ${DEPLOY_SCRIPT}

#start server
${WAS_HOME}/profiles/${PROFILE_NAME}/bin/startServer.sh ${SERVER_NAME}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , can you also let me know if the below script makes sense?

Comment: 1.Command line arguments from uDeploy
environment=$1
cluster=$2
ear=$3

Comment: I cant see any scripts attached. Please check. Also are u using IBM Urbancode for deployment?

Comment: Yes we are using udeploy to invoke this deploy script , i am not able to attach the code here nor type due to word count restrictions:(

Comment: I don't have much experience with Udeploy myself, But from what I know there are off the shelf plugins available in Udeploy which can be used for JVM restarts and application deployment in websphere. Any specific reasons to use bash scripts?

Comment: So , currently in this team they are using udeploy to invoke this deploy script , and my task was to write a wrapper , so that this wrapper would (Stop/invoke deploy script /start WAS).

Comment: !/bin/bash# Stop the cluster
/app/wam/websphere/ws85-setup/websphere-op -e test -c fxoch -a stop 
# Invoke deploy.py
/app/wam/deploy/bin/deploy
# Start the cluster
/app/wam/websphere/ws85-setup/websphere-op -e test -c fxoch -a start

Comment: Updated Script:Could you please check if this will work
!/bin/bash
# Stop the cluster
/app/wam/websphere/ws85-setup/websphere-op -e $1 -c $2 -a stop 
# Invoke deploy.py
/app/wam/deploy/bin/deploy $@
# Start the cluster
/app/wam/websphere/ws85-setup/websphere-op -e $1 -c $2 -a start

#use cluster=$2
#and environment=$1
# ./test $1 $2
#script will need to reside on the deployment manager and uDeploy will need to be able to call it.